# How to test PWA Studio with PreRender.io?

Tags: magento2, seo, pwa-studio

I would like to simulate Googlebot access in my PWA Studio installation.

How could I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can test it by changing the User Agent, on Chrome you can change it on your **Network conditions** tab.

[image: Chrome User agent as Googlebot]

You can also run this Curl command, you might receive the **x-prerender-requestid** header, which shows that your integration is working fine.

```
curl -sSLI -A googlebot https://mystore.com
```

Ref: [How can I test the Integration?](https://docs.prerender.io/docs/14-test-it)